# Google Apps Script: Logger Not Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script

Despite following *many examples* I found online (of varied syntax), I am unable to get *Logger.log(String format, Object.... values): Logger* to format.  [Google's official doc for Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log%28String,Object...%29) states that it works using Java format string syntax for string conversion, but my example code disagrees.  Am I crazy?

**Environment:**

```
Linux (Fedora 17)
Chrome latest (v27.0.1453.110)
Google Apps Script (I assume this engine is server-side...)

$sudo yum install google-chrome-stable.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
Package google-chrome-stable-27.0.1453.110-202711.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**Example Code:**

```
function testLogger() {
  var state = "this";

  Logger.log("Will %s work?", state.toString());
  Logger.log("Will '%s' work?", state.toString());
  Logger.log("Will [%s] work?", state.toString());
  Logger.log('Will "%s" work?', state.toString());
  Logger.log('Will %s work?', state.toString());
  Logger.log('Will [%s] work?', state.toString());

  Logger.log("Will %s work?", state);
  Logger.log("Will '%s' work?", state);
  Logger.log("Will [%s] work?", state);
  Logger.log('Will "%s" work?', state);
  Logger.log('Will %s work?', state);
  Logger.log('Will [%s] work?', state);


  Logger.log('[%s]\t is today', Date());
  Logger.log('[%s]\t is today', Date().toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
[13-06-17 11:33:23:660 PDT] Starting execution
[13-06-17 11:33:23:664 PDT] Logger.log([Will %s work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:664 PDT] Logger.log([Will '%s' work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will [%s] work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will "%s" work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will %s work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will [%s] work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will %s work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will '%s' work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:665 PDT] Logger.log([Will [%s] work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:666 PDT] Logger.log([Will "%s" work?, [this]]) [0.0 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:666 PDT] Logger.log([Will %s work?, [this]]) [0.001 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:666 PDT] Logger.log([Will [%s] work?, [this]]) [0.001 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:666 PDT] Logger.log([[%s]     is today, [Mon Jun 17 2013 11:33:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)]]) [0.001 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:666 PDT] Logger.log([[%s]     is today, [Mon Jun 17 2013 11:33:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)]]) [0.001 seconds]
[13-06-17 11:33:23:667 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.002 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Just to mention, I have of course also searched SO but have not found an answer for this.

Comment: It worked for me. I had pasted the results here, but it's an unreadable blob in a comment.

Comment: @Fred: Thank you.  Could you please confirm which syntax works?  Does every one of my example tests work for you, that is, %s is correctly replaced?

Comment: I copied & pasted the entire thing, and they all worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the output you've pasted, looks like you are barking up the wrong tree. What you are seeing is probably the execution transcript and not the logger output. The Logger output can be accessed by pressing Ctrl-Enter in the script editor.

Comment: Exactly!  Thank you.  As Srik points out, the logger output is correctly formatted, whereas the execution transcript is not.  Both are accessible from 'View' tab in Script Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Output from a standalone script, where it works just fine (as reported by @Fred as well):

```
[13-06-17 15:45:24:889 EDT] Will this work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:889 EDT] Will 'this' work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:889 EDT] Will [this] work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:889 EDT] Will "this" work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:890 EDT] Will this work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:893 EDT] Will [this] work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:893 EDT] Will this work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:894 EDT] Will 'this' work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:894 EDT] Will [this] work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:894 EDT] Will "this" work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:894 EDT] Will this work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:895 EDT] Will [this] work?
[13-06-17 15:45:24:895 EDT] [Mon Jun 17 2013 15:45:24 GMT-0400 (EDT)]    is today
[13-06-17 15:45:24:901 EDT] [Mon Jun 17 2013 15:45:24 GMT-0400 (EDT)]    is today
```

Also validated in a spreadsheet-contained script. If you can repeat your results, please provide more information about the nature of your script.

In the mean time, it looks like you have been the victim of a gremlin.

Comment: I'm perflexed!  I had been running scripts within a FormApp I am developing while logged into GMail with a Google Business account (myEmail@myCompany.ca) but even logging out of gmail completely and logging in with my personal GMail (myEmail@gmail.com) and creating an empty script with _just_ the testLogger() function above gives me the same (incorrect) results.  :/ I will test this at home to eliminate it being anything to do with my company's admin setting or something and will vote tomorrow.  Thank you @Fred, Mogsdad for restoring my sanity.

Comment: I've added my environment to my post for posterity.